# Creating freestyle project from groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is it possible to create new freestyle project and add it to the dashboard view on Jenkins straight from the groovy script?

For example, I want to go through the list of all dependencies for a project. If a dependency is missing from the project list I want to fetch it, create freestyle project and then run the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you need:

```
    @NonCPS
    def createFreestyleProject(String projectName){
        def parent = Jenkins.getInstance()
        //Instantiate a new project
        def project = new FreeStyleProject(parent, projectName);

        //Set a description for the project
        project.setDescription("Just a placeholder for a description")

        //Create a parameter for the project
        def parameterDefinitions = new ArrayList<ParameterDefinition>();
        def name = "ParameterOne"
        def defaultValue = "1"
        def description = "Just a placeholder for a parameter description"
        parameterDefinitions.add(new StringParameterDefinition(name, defaultValue, description))

        //Create a job property for the project
        def jobProperty = new ParametersDefinitionProperty(parameterDefinitions)

        //Adding and saving the job property to the project
        project.addProperty(jobProperty)
        project.save()
        parent.reload()
    }
```

But before this you must do:

```
    import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
    import hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
```